# Jenkins HTML Publisher plugin copying error for JMeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

I am working on sleeve machine for Jenkins. I use Performance plugin for my load tests. I can successfully create jtl log files and publish them on Jenkins. There is no problem with writing and copying jtl log files from master machine. Moreover, I have all permissions.

However when I try HTML publisher plugin for more detailed reports, console gives an error which is

```
ERROR: Directory 'C:\JMeter_3.3\html_files' exists but failed copying to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Test(user1)\htmlreports'.
ERROR: This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded.
```

After this error, HTML reports tag is not shown like Performance Trends. By the way, the job is not pipeline.

Comment: @orinarytester Have you managed to resolve this?